# Adresse als Apposition

Tags: comma, apposition

stellt im folgenden Satz die ausgeschriebene Adresse eine Apposition dar? Und kann ich daher die Satzzeichen so anwenden?

> Darf ich Ihnen diese an die Adresse; Musterstraße, Musterstadt; senden?

Comment: Das *könnte* eine Apposition sein. Spätestens aber, wenn du eine Hausnummer und Postleitzahl einfügst, sieht das ziemlich schräg aus.

Comment: Das erste Semikolon ist m. E. nicht richtig. Aber "... an die Adresse Musterstraße, Musterstadt senden?" oder "... an die Adresse Musterstraße, Musterstadt, senden?" findet man als Beispiel oft.

Comment: Dass es schräg aussieht, sehe ich auch so. Woher kommt dann im zweiten beispiel das komma vor senden?

Comment: Ich habe beim Suchen auf die Schnelle ein Beispiel (Kommasetzung bei Datum) gefunden, das beide Varianten als zulässig genannt hat.

Comment: Für das Datum habe ich diese Regel auch gefunden. Wenn wir das allerdings auf die Adresse anwenden, dann wäre ein Komma vor der Adresse ja auch optional. Das Semikolon wäre in diesem Fall aber falsch, da es nicht bestandteil der Aufzählung selbst ist?

Answer (score 5):

Übliche und bewährte Formen, dies in Schriftsatz zu gießen, wären:

> Darf ich Ihnen diese an die Adresse Müllerstraße 16, 73450 Hüblingen senden?
>
> Darf ich Ihnen diese an die Adresse "Müllerstraße 16, 73450 Hüblingen" senden?
>
> Darf ich Ihnen diese in die Müllerstraße 16, 73450 Hüblingen senden?

Die Strichpunkte, die du im Beispiel verwendest, sind ganz unangebracht. Appositionen werden nie mit Strichpunkten eingefasst. Strichpunkte werden im Deutschen sinnvoll z.B. verwendet, um ansonsten vollständige Sätze abzutrennen, die man jedoch aus inhaltlichen Gründen stärker an den vorhergehenden Satz binden will.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Gibt es denn einen Hintergrund dazu, warum es anders als beim Datum gehandhabt wird?